Бинарный поиск встаёт посреди программы Pycharm
Реализовывал простую программу для сортировки массива данных, решил для удобства использовать бинарный поиск. Для маленького количества данных всё работало, как только количество элементов стало 21+, программа просто намертво встала, а в иных случаях вылетала ошибка "MemoryError: Stack overflow", помогите пожалуйста, в чем ошибка?
def binfound(x, a, low, hight):
    mid = len(a) // 2

    while low!=hight:
        if x >= a[mid]:
            low = mid + 1
        else:
            hight = mid - 1
        mid = (low + hight) // 2
    return mid+1 if x>=a[mid] else mid

b = [123,12,4,567,123,89876,543,765432,7654432543,7654,6543,8765432,654323,32,1,765432,6543,6543,765,432,554321,7654,54,432,4535874564456456,543,5,4332,65,432135,32,432,4321,654342,9,87876,76543,237654,321,765432,7654323,43445]


q = [0]

for i in b:
    x = binfound(i, q, 0, len(q) - 1)
    q = q[0:x] + [i] + q[x:]
    print(q)


Ну так отлаживай. Кстати, при q = q[0:x] + [i] + q[x:] бинпоиск нафиг не нужен.

mid = len(a) // 2 - это баг.

совет: лучше в циклах не писать строгие сравнения на индексы, типа пока a!=0. Лучше отсекать сразу ту часть, которую не могут принять индексы. В данном случае low, height - следует написать пока low < height

иначе может не обработаться случай, когда low неожиданно перескочила height и стала больше него

@ArtemLP, не должно быть такого случая...

low = 0
hight = 1
mid = 0


else:
   hight = mid - 1


high = -1

Это неправильно. Бинпоиск никогда не должен искать вне диапазона. Ну и зацикливается тоже из-за неё.
Кажется, должно быть
hight = mid


А ещё ошибка тут:

mid = len(a) // 2



Замена условия продолжения цикла на while low<hight: чинит ситуацию с зацикливанием. И вроде сортировка правильная получается при этом.

В самой функции есть спорные моменты. Например условие, где вы сравниваете искомый элемент х с  а[mid] на >=. Т.е. даже в случае если функция нашла элемент, цикл всё равно сдвигает границу left за пределы найденного элемента индекса mid. Наверное стоит сделать принудительный выход из цикла, когда мы нашли элемент, т.е. добавить отдельную проверку в виде условия.
Также следует обратить внимание на строгое условие сравнения в цикле. Лучше обезопасить себя и написать left < height.


Массив q меняется. В нём в итоге должен получиться отсортированный b. 2. Искать по b бинпоиском в принципе нельзя - он не отсортирован. 3. Вполне возможно, что он хочет сдвигать при равенстве. По крайней мере, даже если надо найти последний из равных, то выхода на равном быть не должно. А вполне может быть, что он ищет минимальный больший x. В любом случае, не кажется, что это причина зацикливания.



left < height может и может быть решением проблемы (хотя я такую ситуацию без отладки придумать не смог), но почти наверняка, если бинпоиск докатился до такого состояния, то он всё равно ищет неверно. По идее < и != должны делать одно и то же.


@Qwertiy, вы были правы ошибка именно в знаке !=, спасибо большое

@user589204, во-первых, я такого не говорил, во-вторых, ошибка в другом месте.
